# "Both are right" or "either are right"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Can we use "**either are right**" to mean "**both are right**?"

Answer (score 9):

No.

"both" takes a plural verb - it refers to two things.

"either" takes a singular verb - it refers to one of two things.

> "both **are** right"
>
> "either **is** right"

Once you have corrected the grammar, you need to look at the logic.

> 'both' is inclusive - it goes with logical AND.
>
> 'either' can be  equivalent to logical OR or XOR depending on the context.

**Examples**

**1.**

"John says that horses are mammals but Freda says that they are quadrupeds. Who is right?"

"Both are right. Horses are simultaneously quadrupeds and mammals."

**2.**

"John says you should wear black shoes, Freda says you should wear white shoes. Who is right?"

"Either is right. It depends entirely on the rest of your outfit."

Comment: On Sunday I was at Chester Zoo with my family. As you drive into the car park, large notices scream at you *USE BOTH LANES*. Any driver taking the instruction literally would drive in straddling the centre line. I think what they mean is *USE EITHER LANE*. It seems to depend on whether a traffic notice addresses one driver, or the collective of the traffic.

Comment: @WS2 - Haha! I love that sort of thing. There's an ancient joke about this.  http://www.cleanjokeoftheday.com/jokes-dottedlinetear.html

Comment: But ***“Either** horses **or** mules **are** required.”*

Comment: @tchrist - good catch (+1). I didn't spot that. I think I'll leave things as they are because I answered the question in two ways. The real question wasn't about grammar, it was about equivalence. I think my discussion about logic is correct independent of the verb conjugation.